# Javascript: Get object with date range in array which matches to the current time

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

Please correct me if this question has already been asked on Stack, but I haven't found any answer which would solve my problem. I want to display only the object of my array, where the date range, consisting of `timeStart` and `timeEnd`, matches to the current time. Let's say the current time would be `2020-10-22T16:35:45+01:00`, the function should display **Steve** (see the example given below) it's appointment. **How can I search for the object where the current time is in between the given date ranges?**

```
const currentTime = Date.now(); // 2020-10-22T16:35:45+01:00
```

This is the array I'm working with:

```
[
    {
        name: "Thomas",
        timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:00:00+0100",
        timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:15:00+01:00"
    },
    {
        name: "Marc",
        timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:15:00+0100",
        timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:30:00+01:00"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve",
        timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:30:00+0100",
        timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:45:00+01:00"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the start, end and current dates inside a [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) loop.
If the comparison returns true then the current object will be returned, otherwise `undefined`.

```js
const now = new Date("2020-10-22T16:17:00+01:00"); // 16:17. Should be Marc.

const dates = [
    {
        name: "Thomas",
        timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:00:00+0100",
        timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:15:00+01:00"
    },
    {
        name: "Marc",
        timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:15:00+0100",
        timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:30:00+01:00"
    },
    {
        name: "Steve",
        timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:30:00+0100",
        timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:45:00+01:00"
    }
];

const result = dates.find(({ timeStart, timeEnd }) => {
  const start = new Date(timeStart);
  const end = new Date(timeEnd);
  return start <= now && end > now;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? It searches every date and makes sure that the current date is between the start and end.

```js
const currentTime = Date.now(); // 2020-10-22T16:35:45+01:00

const dates = [{
    name: "Thomas",
    timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:00:00+0100",
    timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:15:00+01:00"
  },
  {
    name: "Marc",
    timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:15:00+0100",
    timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:30:00+01:00"
  },
  {
    name: "Steve",
    timeStart: "2020-10-22T16:30:00+0100",
    timeEnd: "2020-10-22T16:45:00+01:00"
  }
];

// If you want only one result, use find instead of filter
const validDates = dates.filter((obj) => {
  // Converts strings to Dates
  let startDate = new Date(obj.timeStart);
  let endDate = new Date(obj.timeEnd);
  // Makes sure the current time is after the start date and before the end date
  return currentTime >= startDate && currentTime <= endDate;
});

console.log(validDates);

// To get name, use validDates[0].name (for filter, see above) or validDates.name (for find)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
yourArray.filter(item =>  currentTime >= item.timeStart &&
currenttime <= timeEnd)

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
const currentTime = Date.now();

const resultArray=yourArray.filter(item=>{
      // you have to format dates to be able to compare them
      return item.timeStart < currentTime && item.timeEnd > currentTime
      });
```